# Represent a List of Objects in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

How I can represent a list of objects in XSD, for example, given a XML like this?

```
 <msgBody>
  <Contato>
   <cdEndereco>11</cdAreaRegistro>
   <cdBairro>99797781</nrLinha>
   <email>foo@foo.com</email>
  </Contato>
  <Contato>
   <cdEndereco>11</cdAreaRegistro>
   <cdBairro>99797781</nrLinha>
   <email>foo@foo.com</email>
  </Contato>
 </msgBody>
```

How I can merge it into a list of object type Contato?

Comment: Isn't such XML a little bit malformed, e.g <cdEndereco>11</cdAreaRegistro>

Answer (score 17):

I may suggest the following schema (even though your XML is broken as pasted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="msgBody">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Contato"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Contato">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="cdEndereco"/>
        <xs:element ref="cdBairro"/>
        <xs:element ref="email"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="cdEndereco" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="cdBairro" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: hi, i will try this, and yes, the xml that i paste here is only a part of complete xml. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Use a sequence as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="msgBody">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Contato" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:int" name="cdEndereco"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:int" name="cdBairro"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="email"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```