# How to represent a polymorphic list on xml and xsd?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xmlserializer

I want to create an xml based on xsd, which will be loaded into C# objects at runtime using `XmlSerializer` and `StreamReader`.

My C# objects should have a structure as in this example:

```
class Repository {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<IPerson> Persons { get; set; }
}

interface IPerson {
   int ID { get; set; }
}

class Student : IPerson { 
   int ID { get; set; }  
   string Faculty { get; set; }
}

class Fireman : IPerson { 
   int ID { get; set; }  
   bool IsOfficer { get; set; }
}

class Giant : IPerson { 
   int ID { get; set; }  
   int Height { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to put different implementations of `IPerson` on the xml and have them loaded into the correct types at runtime.

I understand how to define an abstract type and extension types in xsd.

```
<xs:complexType abstract="true" name="IPerson">
  <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Student">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="IPerson">
      <xs:attribute name="Faculty" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Fireman">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="IPerson">
      <xs:attribute name="IsOfficer" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Giant">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="IPerson">
      <xs:attribute name="Height" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

How should the polymorphic list `Persons` be represented on the xsd and xml as part of the type `Repository`?

Comment: xs:sequence?  Are your requirements any different to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740221/represent-a-list-of-objects-in-xsd

Comment: What I always do is create test data using the classes and then serialize the classes to xml file.  Then do reverse and de-serialize the xml file.  If you can serialize the data, then you can de-serialize the results.  The output xml will give you a template to create your schema.